# If $A\perp B$, and $A,B$ are closed subspaces of a Hilbert space, show that $A\bigoplus B$ is closed (What am I misunderstanding?)

Tags: hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

By definition we have that $A\bigoplus B=\{a+b:a\in A, b\in B\}$.

So why can't I just take $a_n+b_n$ to be a convergent sequence in $A\bigoplus B$. Then, by closure of $A$ and $B$ we'd get that $\exists a,b\in A,B$ such that $a_n\to a, b_n\to b$. Thus $a_n+b_n\to a+b\in A\bigoplus B$.

I'm sure this proof is wrong, since I didn't use completeness of hilbert spaces, nor did I use orthogonality of $A$ and $B$. But I really don't see what I'm missing here.

I'm particularly interested why we need $A\perp B$. It seems to me like the claim should be true even if the two spaces aren't orthogonal.

Any clarification that can be offered would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $(a_n+b_n)$ converges, how do you know $(a_n)$ converges? If the sum of $A$ and $B$ was not direct it needn't. Could you show $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: You did not assume orthogonality anywhere in the statement

Comment: Ahh. I think I get it now.

Since we're working in a hilbert space, $(a_n+b_n)$ being convergent means that it's cauchy. So we can find $N$ so that $||(a_n+b_n)-(a_m+b_m)||=||(a_n-a_m)+(b_n-b_m)|| = ||a_n+a_m||+||(b_n-b_m)||<\epsilon$, where the last equality follows from the pythagorean theorem for orthogonal elements. Since $||a_n-a_m||<||a_n-a_m||+||b_n-b_m||$, we have convergence of $a_n$.

Is this the right idea?